# Deserialize multiple values with boost::serialize (with SSCCE)

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I try to serialize and deserialize an object with boost::serialize library. I need to split my save and load function.

I use the library is described in the official tutorial. My save and load functions look like this:

```
friend class boost::serialization::access;

template<typename Archive>
void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned version) const {
    ar & name;
    ar & NType;
    ar & NTherm;
    ar & NRun;
//...
}

template<class Archive>
void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
    ar & name;
    ar & NType;
    ar & NTherm;
    ar & NRun;
//...
}
BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
```

These functions are implemented in the header of a class. I serialize and deserialize like this:
    {
        //Serialize
        std::ofstream ofs("output.txt");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << Object;
    }

```
{
    //Deserialize
    Class newObject;
    std::ifstream ifs("output.txt");
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> newObject;
}
```

Serialization works fine but while deserialization throws an exception at `ar & NRun;`.

An error message pops up which says: *This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.* Debugging showed that an exception *class name too long* was thrown.

How can I fix this?

**Update:** Added brackets in the code snippet.

**Update2:** I added an SSCCE.

*main.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "simulation.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>


int main()
{
    Simulation *sim;
    sim = new Simulation(2,25,25,25,100,500,1000,"Sim");
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("output.txt");
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << sim;
    }

    {
        Simulation newSim;
        std::ifstream ifs("output.txt",std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> newSim;
    }
}
```

*simulation.h*:

```
#ifndef SIMULATION_H_
#define SIMULATION_H_
#include <string>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>

class Simulation {

public:
    //Constructors
Simulation(int anzType, int x=25, int y=25, int z=25, int NT = 100, int NS = 500, int NR = 1000, std::string n = "");
Simulation();           //Defaultconstructor für Boost Serialisierung

    //Destructor
    virtual ~Simulation();


private:
    int NType;             
    int NTherm;             
    int NStep;             
    int NRun;             
    std::string name;
    int Lx;
    int Ly;
    int Lz;
    int LyLz;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<typename Archive>
    void save(Archive& ar, const unsigned version) const {
        ar & name;
        ar & NType;
        ar & NTherm;
        ar & NRun;
        ar & NStep;
    }

    template<class Archive>
    void load(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        ar & name;
        ar & NType;
        ar & NTherm;
        ar & NRun;
        ar & NStep;
    }
    BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
};
#endif /* SIMULATION_H_ */
```

*simulation.cpp*:

```
#include "Simulation.h"


Simulation::Simulation() {

}


Simulation::Simulation(int anzType, int x, int y, int z, int NT, int NS, int NR, std::string n) {
    name = n;
   NType = anzType;
   NTherm = NT;
    NStep = NS;
    NRun = NR;
    Lx = x;
    Ly = y;
    Lz = z;
    LyLz = y*z;
}

Simulation::~Simulation() {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE** Since you updated the question with a SSCCE, it's obvious.

You serialize a `Simulation*`. And then you try to deserialize a `Simulation&`. Unsurprisingly, this won't work.

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bd517ba7aeb35eb)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/access.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

class Simulation {

  public:
    // Constructors
    Simulation(int anzType, int x = 25, int y = 25, int z = 25, int NT = 100, int NS = 500, int NR = 1000, std::string n = "");
    Simulation(); // Defaultconstructor für Boost Serialisierung

    // Destructor
    virtual ~Simulation();

  private:
    std::string name;
    int         NType, NTherm, NStep, NRun;
    int         Lx, Ly, Lz, LyLz;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template <typename Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned) {
        ar & name;
        ar & NType;
        ar & NTherm;
        ar & NRun;
        ar & NStep;
    }
};

Simulation::Simulation() {}

Simulation::Simulation(int anzType, int x, int y, int z, int NT, int NS, int NR, std::string n)
  : name(n), NType(anzType), NTherm(NT), NStep(NS), NRun(NR),
    Lx(x), Ly(y), Lz(z), LyLz(y * z)
{
}

Simulation::~Simulation() {}

int main() {
    Simulation *sim = new Simulation(2, 25, 25, 25, 100, 500, 1000, "Sim");
    {
        std::ofstream ofs("output.txt", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
        oa << sim;
    }

    {
        Simulation* newSim = nullptr;
        std::ifstream ifs("output.txt", std::ios::binary);
        boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
        ia >> newSim;

        delete newSim;
    }
}
```

Comment: Neather `std::ios::binary` nor explicit flushing solves the problem. The streams are used in seperate functions in the program.

Comment: Then you need to make this a SSCCE. The code is ok. The problem is elsewhere

Comment: I've just seen that the programm seems to output the following error: `Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.`

Comment: @pyman I've just noticed your update. I match it with a suitably updated answer. Next time, consider showing the relevant details. (There was zero reason for us to assume that `Object` was not, in fact, an object :))

Comment: Oops. I don't code in C++ that long and just missed it. Of course it's obvious...